# How to (left/right)join two tables?

Tags: sql-server, join

I tried to find out the product id with its missing necessary version.
The following query shows the example:

```
DECLARE @ProductWithVersion TABLE(ProductId int, VersionId int)
insert into @ProductWithVersion values(1281,7),(2220,8)

DECLARE @NecessaryVersion TABLE(VersionId int)
insert into @NecessaryVersion values(7),(8),(9)
```

I want to show the mapping result like:

```
ProductId       VerisonId       VersionId
 1281               7               7
 1281               null            8
 1281               null            9
 2220               null            7
 2220               8               8
 2220               null            9
```

That means, the VersionId from @NecessaryVersion should show all of them(7,8,9), and the VersionId from @ProductWithVersion will show **null** if there is no mapping VersionId with @NecessaryVersion.

I can't figure it out since it is more complicated than left join or right join...

Comment: Shouldn't the `@NecessaryVersion` table also contain the `ProducdId`?

Comment: What result would you want if there were 2 product ids?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an intermediary `cross join` of `ProductId` like so:

```
select p.ProductId, pv.VersionId, n.VersionId
from @NecessaryVersion n
  cross join (select distinct ProductId from @ProductWithVersion i) as p
  left join @ProductWithVersion pv
    on p.ProductId = pv.ProductId
    and n.VersionId = pv.VersionId
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/VNITDI69180

returns:

```
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| ProductId | VersionId | VersionId |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|      1281 | 7         |         7 |
|      1281 | NULL      |         8 |
|      1281 | NULL      |         9 |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

---

If you have a table of where `ProductId` is unique, you could use that instead of selecting the `distinct ProductId` from some source.

---

For the updated example data, rextester demo: http://rextester.com/LVMFO44017

The same query (with an `order by`) returns:

returns:

```
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| ProductId | VersionId | VersionId |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|      1281 | 7         |         7 |
|      1281 | NULL      |         8 |
|      1281 | NULL      |         9 |
|      2220 | NULL      |         7 |
|      2220 | 8         |         8 |
|      2220 | NULL      |         9 |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

Comment: Thanks, no need to worry about the "order by". Yours works well!!